# Git commands for merge down process which doesn't remember previous reverts

Tags: git

Below is a description of what I want to achieve:

I have a master branch on our git repo.

Every month there is a date on which I completely copy the master branch code on 'secondary' branch. Our intention is to completely replace secondary branch with master code like a hard copy and replace. I don’t need any code on secondary branch to be retained.

Once the hard copy and replace is done, I shall remove a list of commits from the 'secondary' branch which I don’t need.

Below is how multiple cycles would look like:

1) August Monthly Merge Down (from master to secondary) Day:
    a) Hard Copy and replace secondary branch with master branch code.
    b) Remove a list of commits from secondary branch ( I was using git revert command for this which had caused problems; more on this later)

2) September Monthly Merge Down (from master to secondary) Day:
    a) Hard Copy and replace secondary branch with master branch code.
    b) Remove a list of commits from secondary branch

I was following the below git commands each cycle:

On master branch:

```
    1.    git fetch
    2.    git checkout secondary
    3.    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/secondary (only the first time after the branch is created)
    4.    git fetch origin
    5.    git reset --hard origin/master
    6.    git status
    7.    git commit -a
    8.    git status
    9.    git push origin secondary
    11.  git revert 10d3ed335687ef5925c40bd723c81688b7b532c0
    11.  git revert 8e6cb3c361cb415f60d12b26ac547929ec2311de
    12.  git status
    13.  git push origin secondary
```

The problem with this process is that:
Ideally I don't want the git reverts done in the August cycle to be remembered or honored in the September cycle because I are going for a full hard replace of secondary branch with master. But, as observed, that's not the case. The reverts done in the previous cycles are remembered for the next cycle too (which I don't want to happen).

So, looks like git revert is not the right command here for our requirement.

Can you suggest us the right git commands and steps to achieve our requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by a "hard copy and replace"?

Comment: As in, I want 'secondary' branch to be an exact copy of 'master' branch. Nothing more. Nothing less.

Comment: How do you determine which commits you want to revert?

Comment: And what do you mean by "The reverts done in the previous cycles are remembered for the next cycle too"? Do you mean that you have to do the same reverts every time?

Comment: That is determined based on our internal list which is provided by other teams. eg: Simple tab name changes which wouldn't work on the secondary branch, because it runs on a different environment.

Comment: For every cycle, there is a different set of reverts (not related to the earlier cycle). What I have noticed after a few cycles is that, the reverts done in August cycle are not being cleared by the September reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197186/discussion-between-insecurenoob-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: `git revert <commit>` creates a new commit that "undoes" the changes in  <commit>. When you do `git reset --hard origin/master`, those "undo" commits should no longer exist on your secondary branch.

Comment: "*Simple tab name changes which wouldn't work on the secondary branch, because it runs on a different environment*" Rather than branch surgery, this sounds like it would be better solved with a better configuration system. There are any number of answers about managing that, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992361/how-to-organise-projects-in-git-for-two-projects-with-shared-modules/57023971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `git reset --hard origin/master` resets your local branch to the commit where `origin/master` currently points. You can even update the central repo with `git push -f origin secondary`. However, any other people on your team who have previously pulled `secondary` maintain the same history that originally existed on that branch. When they do `git pull`, they only merge the modified `secondary` branch from the central repo into their local repo. The previous reverts are still maintained.

To fix this, they can do the following:

```
git fetch
git checkout secondary
git reset --hard origin/secondary
```

However, this seems like a strange workflow for deployment. Your example in the comments suggests that you need configuration for your project that allows you to deploy to different environments without changing any code.